# undefined method `paginate' issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pagination, sunspot, will-paginate

I have the following code in my controller:

```
def index
  @search = Product.search do |query|
    query.fulltext params[:sSearch]
    query.with(:store_id, @store.id)
  end
  products = @search.results.paginate(page).per_page(per_page)
end

private
  def page
     params[:iDisplayStart].to_i/per_page + 1
  end

  def per_page
     params[:iDisplayLength].to_i > 0 ? params[:iDisplayLength].to_i : 10
  end
```

but I get the error:

```
undefined method `paginate' for #<Sunspot::Search::PaginatedCollection:0x007f86243ac440>
```

Comment: are you using a pagination gem, if so do specify which in your question

Comment: Yes, I'm using will_paginate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use within the search block:

```
@search = Product.search do |query|
    query.paginate page: page, per_page: per_page
end
```

You do not need to use the query variable in the block. You can invoke methods directly within the block.

```
@search = Product.search do
    fulltext params[:sSearch]
    with(:store_id, @store.id)
    paginate page: page, per_page: per_page
end
```